# can i use js variable as index of mvc array?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an array model in mvc passed to html page
I also have few divs of ".myClass" , if any of them is clicked I call function and getting their id ( each one has different integer id ) and then I want to use this id as index of an array, how can i do that? cause this code isn't working.

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function (event) {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    $("#Paragraph").html("@Model[id].name");
});
```

Comment: need to output your server side array to a javascript variable as json to do that

Comment: This is not possible because the JavaScript code runs in the browser and the C# code runs on the server, both at different times. You need to refresh the page after the click with an attribute that has the new ID and then use request parameters in the MVC view.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer that's a very old school way of thinking

Comment: You feel like dumping an entire array into the JavaScript code is any better? What I wrote can be done using XHR or WebSockets.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer sure...but xhr is probably more along lines of what OP wants as opposed to refreshing page. if data isn't huge passing directly to javascript variable isn't a big deal either

Comment: Whether OP refreshed the page or uses XHR or WS is totally beside the point. The point is you can't mix C# and JS, you need to talk to the server somehow. OP never expressed preference for sync or async and frankly it's not important at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix server code in js like that as the C# code will be executed on server when razor tries to render the page. Your click event happens in client side after razor sends the generated markup.

For your specific use case, first you need to read your Model and set that a local javascript array. Then you can read an item from that array.

Assuming your Model is of some collection type.

```
$(function(){

  //Store the Model to a local js variable.
  var myArr = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));

  $(document).on('click', '.myClass', function (event) {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    $("#Paragraph").html(myArr[id].name);
  });

});
```

Another option is to make an ajax call to your server where your action method accepts the unique id, using which it rebuilds the entity and send back to the client and client will use it.